# Deleting child nodes that contains condition

Tags: javascript

I'm asking for help with this issue:

Given this xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OutputDocumentMessage xmlns="">
    <Recipient>
        <Id>A</Id>
        <IsPrimary>N</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>B</Id>
        <IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>E</Id>
        <IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>D</Id>
        <IsPrimary>N</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>E</Id>
        <IsPrimary>N</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>F</Id>
        <IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>E</Id>
        <IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>G</Id>
        <IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
</OutputDocumentMessage>
```

I'd like to remove all  nodes where child node "Id" contains value "E". Intended result should show like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OutputDocumentMessage xmlns="">
    <Recipient>
        <Id>A</Id>
        <IsPrimary>N</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>B</Id>
        <IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>D</Id>
        <IsPrimary>N</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>F</Id>
        <IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>G</Id>
        <IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
</OutputDocumentMessage>
```

I'm using this code:

```
// Create the output message
var next = output.append(input[0]);

// Create the output message as XML
var myXml = next.xml;

// Check how many repeats of Recipient  
var receptientRepeatCount = next.getRepeatCount("/OutputDocumentMessage/Recipient");

// iterate through each recipient repeat, deleting the node if 'Recipient.IsId' equals 'E'
for (var i = 1; i <= receptientRepeatCount; i++) {
     var isId = next.getField("/OutputDocumentMessage/Recipient[" + i + "]/Id");
   if(isId == "E")
   {
         delete myXml.*::Recipient[i-1];
    }
}
next.xml = myXml;
```

But it stills contains child nodes with Id value equals "E":

```
<OutputDocumentMessage>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>A</Id>
        <IsPrimary>N</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>B</Id>
        <IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>D</Id>
        <IsPrimary>N</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>E</Id>
        <IsPrimary>N</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>E</Id>
        <IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
    <Recipient>
        <Id>G</Id>
        <IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary>
    </Recipient>
</OutputDocumentMessage>
```

What's wrong with my code? Your help is much appreciated.
Regards,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [DOMParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).
- Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target your elements
- [.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove) the elements which [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) matches a string

```js
const xmlStr = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OutputDocumentMessage xmlns="">
    <Recipient><Id>A</Id><IsPrimary>N</IsPrimary></Recipient>
    <Recipient><Id>B</Id><IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary></Recipient>
    <Recipient><Id>E</Id><IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary></Recipient>
    <Recipient><Id>D</Id><IsPrimary>N</IsPrimary></Recipient>
    <Recipient><Id>E</Id><IsPrimary>N</IsPrimary></Recipient>
    <Recipient><Id>F</Id><IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary></Recipient>
    <Recipient><Id>E</Id><IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary></Recipient>
    <Recipient><Id>G</Id><IsPrimary>Y</IsPrimary></Recipient>
</OutputDocumentMessage>`;

const DP = new DOMParser();
const XMLDoc = DP.parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");

XMLDoc.querySelectorAll("Recipient").forEach(elRecipient => {
  const elId = elRecipient.querySelector("Id");
  if (elId.textContent.trim() === "E") elRecipient.remove();
});

console.log(XMLDoc.documentElement.outerHTML)
```

Comment: @jpc2879 those are not *libraries*. It's pure JavaScript.